# Connecting canvas items together in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

What I would like to do is visually "connect" items on a canvas. For example, allowing the user to draw a line from one image to a second image and then these two are connected.

By connected here I mean that if the user clicks on and moves one image, the the line resizes to retain the connection. In essence, the images would become the endpoints for the line, and more than one image can be connected to a third image.

Is there a way to detect if a line is touching the edge of an image?

This brings me to my second question, is there a way to resize lines on a canvas in this dynamic way? The solution I have tried is basically deleting the original line and redrawing a new line, but this isn't exactly what I would like.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the endpoints of lines (thus moving them or making them longer or shorter) by using the [coords](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.coords-method) method. You'll have to keep track of the lines associated with an object and update the endpoints when the image is moved.

Comment: I have references to the lines stored, so this does work, what I'm having a more difficult time with is what I just commented on above, which is I'm not sure how to detect if a line has touched the edge of an image.

Comment: @user2148990: you cannot detect if two objects touch without doing the math yourself. Perhaps instead of connecting a line to an edge of an image, you connect to the center of the image. Then you just have to keep a little list of which objects each line is associate with, and the coordinates of the line are simply the center points of the two images that it connects.

Comment: I've considered this but I want to be able to connect two lines to one image, each line representing a different input. It would be confusing for the user I think to have both lines shoot to the middle of the image. Also I may string multiple images together and again all of these lines eminating from center might be odd looking